# Question about algebraic curve being birational to smooth projective curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a geometrically irreducible affine variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and dimension $1$. Then it is known that $X$ is birational over $\mathbb{C}$ to a smooth projective curve $C$.

I was interested in knowing in what situations, or under which hypotheses, can we guarantee that it is in fact birational over $\mathbb{Q}$ and that $C$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$? Is something like this known?

Comment: This works over $\mathbb Q$, or indeed over any perfect field.

Comment: @WillSawin Good to know, thank you! If you could give me an idea how I can prove this, I would appreciate it!